# Unable to export an ipa file in azure devops

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I'm trying to build a CI pipeline for my xCode project. I've been struggling with this for the past 2 days.

These are the tasks used in my pipeline:

1. Install an Apple Certificate
2. Install an Apple provisioning profile
3. pod install
4. Xcode build & clean
5. Copy files to $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
6. Publish Artifacts to drop folder

I've seen in the documentation that we need to check the `Create App Package` checkbox if we need to have and `ipa` package. But whenever I check the check

> ❌  error: No profile for team 'teamID' matching 'provision_name.mobileprovision' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'teamId/provision_name.mobileprovision'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target 'project_name' from project 'project_name')

Here's a two snippets about signing and exporting options in xCode build task:

[image: Signing & provisioning]

[image: Package Options]

So anyone have an idea why this issue is happening?

Comment: Try set in the Signing Style option automatic and in the Team ID paste the id of the team that you can find in the developer site or using Xcode before the group ID.

Comment: Remove the provisioning profile name. You only need the UUID from the variable. The variable is populated by your install provisioning profile step.  If this doesn't help, please add your .yml file to the question.

Comment: @Andrea your solution didn't work, following error has been thrown `❌  error: RDAAPP.iOS has conflicting provisioning settings. RDAAPP.iOS is automatically signed, but provisioning profile RDAIII Services Viewer Provisioning Profile has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'RDAAPP.iOS' from project 'RDAAPP.iOS')`

Comment: @Paulw11 how do I get the populated variable??

Comment: If you have  an `InstallAppleProvisioningProfile` and an `InstallAppleCertificate` task then the variables will be set for you

Comment: @Paulw11 you were right, everything worked fine. I left the Provisioning profile name empty and the pipeline succeeded, also an `.ipa` file was created. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Paulw11` mentioned in his comments above, the issue was in setting the name of the provisioning profile in `Signing & Provisioning` section.

As he said, the `Install an Apple provisioning profile` will set the `UUID` variable needed in the task mentioned above. It will be populated while the pipeline is running.

So here's the working pipeline for me now:

**Tasks:**

[image: Pipeline Tasks]

**Signing & provisioning properties:**

[image: Signing & provisioning properties]

**Package options:**

[image: Package options]

Comment: Thanks for sharing the picture of configuration , it helped me resolved the issue , I was passing the values for signing identity and provisioning profile UUID but instead I needed to defined a variable and call those variables in the required fields

Comment: @AnwarGul really glad I was able to help you :)!